# Scroll Vertical y horizontal en un UITableView swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll-view

alguien me puede sugerir cual sería la mejor práctica para hacer una tabla que tiene scroll vertical y horizontal, con la primera columna fixed o fija cuando me desplazo horizontalmente hacia la derecha. Adjunto imagen de un ejemplo de como sería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay scroll horizontal en una tabla si usas código nativo. Con Xcode puede diseñar tu celda ajustable el ancho para que se visualice mejor tu data. Ese ejemplo parece html, es una app híbrida?

Comment: Hola, en realidad ese ejemplo que pasé es de puro diseño pero tiene que ser nativo.

Comment: Puedes agregar en tu Xcode. New-> Cocoa Class, ingresas un nombre y en subclass seleccionas `UITableViewCell`, esa es la celda en donde debes agregar los datos. No te olvides de `Also create a XIB file`

Comment: te recomiendo usar collectionView en lugar de tableView

Comment: Hola Luffy pero el scroll view no tiene scroll horizontal

Comment: Crea un scrollview horizontal y crea un tableview vertical como hijo del scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Como te indiqué en el comentario, no es posible el scroll horizontal.
Entonces agregando la celda quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes modificar el ancho y agregar los labels que necesites. En este ejemplo la celda es de tipo `Subtitle`.

Debes agregar un identificador a la celda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar los datos si lo haces desde una API o SQLite lo haces de esta manera:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Agregas el número de secciones.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Agregas el número de filas.
        return 5
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        // Configuras los datos de tu celda
        cell.textLabel?.text = "John Smith"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "10000000"
        

        return cell
    }
```

Al compilar tendrías así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu diseño debes ajustarlo a como trabajan las celdas en iOS. Espero te sirva y recuerda revisar la documentación de Apple con respecto al User Interface.

Comment: Muchas gracias, bueno en realidad en funcionamiento de la tabla basica si lo tengo claro mi duda es como hacer ese scroll horizontal ya que asi es el diseño de la app. He intentado con un uiscroll view pero no logro adaptarla al 100 como se necesita con la primera columna fija al desplazarme horizontalmente

Comment: No he visto ninguna App en el AppStore que haga scroll horizontal a una celda. Ni las híbridas. Pero como te digo debes revisar esta guía para que tu app no sea rechazada: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/.